# Can't connect Windows shared printer with samba share in cent OS (Production server)

Tags: php, centos, samba, thermal-printer

I have an e-commerce website hosted in **cent OS** server. Now am trying to print order invoice to a EPOS printer connected in windows 10. I am using [mike42's ESC/POS-PHP Print Driver](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) to achieve this. But i cant connect to my printer using **samba share**. In localhost everything is working fine. But in production server i cant achieve this.

windows printer is already shared and connected in USB port.

**smb.conf** file is as follows:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        security = user

        wins support = yes
        hostname lookups = yes
        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0775
        browseable = Yes
        guest ok = Yes
        read only = no
        public = yes

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
```

This is the command am trying to test:

```
echo "Hello world" | smbclient "//my_system_name/Printer_name" system_password -U "WORKGROUP\system_user" -C "print -"
```

By entering this command am getting the following error:

*connection to 'my_system_name' failed (error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)*

I really appreciate any help you can provide.